# Sql count include item with no value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different database from each library. Below is the sample data

```
Table Store
Book Inventory
AAA x
AAA x
AAA x
AAA x
AAB x
AAB x
AAC x

Book Inventory
AAA x
AAA x
AAA x
AAB x
AAD x
AAE x


SELECT Book, COUNT(book) from Store where book in ('AAA','AAB','AAC','AAD','AAE') group by Book
```

The result skipped those book with 0 value. How do i get return result even if the count is 0?

```
Expected result
AAA 4
AAB 2
AAC 1
AAD 0
AAE 0

AAA 3
AAB 1
AAC 0
AAD 1
AAE 1
```

Comment: Please make your question understandable adding relevant resources like `your create table code, sample input and expected output`. Thank you

Comment: whose data not available in table then how query get count ?

Comment: do you want count of books or sum of inventory per book?

Comment: And why there are two sets of input?

Comment: there is any one table where all books record is exist ? or there is only limited books like above(5 books)?

Comment: there is only 1 table with all the book exist
but let say i only want to select 5 of them. i must be able to count each of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Book, SUM(book in ('AAA','AAB','AAC','AAD','AAE') ) AS cnt
from Store 
group by Book
```

Comment: This query work but, if the list contains more book it will show everything.
I only want to show the 5 record i selected

Comment: I didn't get ur meaning